# How to retrieve data for a specific user in Kinvey on Android

Tags: kinvey

I know this may be a simple question, but I've searched everywhere for an answer.  I created two different users in Kinvey, and I want to extract the data for a specific user (only one of the two).  If I use the mygears.get(new KinveyListCallback() command, I get all the data.  How do I retrieve the data for a specific user?

Comment: Here is my load code to be more specific.

Comment: Just in case anyone else ever has this question, I finally found the answer.  Use a query like  query.equals("_acl.creator",kinveyClient.user().getId());

Answer (score 0):

In your specific reference instead of calling:

```
query.equals("_acl.creator",kinveyClient.user().getId());
```

You are probably better to call:

```
query.equals("_id",kinveyClient.user().getId());
```

The creator of a user is generally the user itself, however it may not always be the case.

Also I'm not sure what client language you are specifically using but here are some references.

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/users#lookup
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/users#lookup

Comment: Hello Aidan, can you help this question: Thanks for the help can you also support this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/35285825/kinvey-rest-api-upload